# log() instruction leads to build error : cannot find symbol "to()"

Tags: apache-camel

When I try to compile this

```
    from(rule.getInput().getUrl()).
    log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "New incoming message, rule n°"+getRule().getId()).
    routeId(getId()).
    filter().method(rule, "verify").
    to(outputs);
```

I have a build error :

```
MVN : C:\........\DynamicRouteBuilder.java:[38,33] cannot find symbol
MVN : symbol  : method to(java.lang.String[])
```

( `to(java.lang.String[])` refers to `to(outputs)` )

But if I remove the log row :

```
        from(rule.getInput().getUrl()).
        //log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "New incoming message, rule n°"+getRule().getId()).
        routeId(getId()).
        filter().method(rule, "verify").
        to(outputs);
```

It works!

It also works if I move the log row beetween filter() and to().

I can't see why. Any clue?

Comment: Could it be that you use a non ASCII char in the log message, eg the ", rule nX" where X is that char?

Comment: @ClausIbsen : No, I have the same error when I remove it.

Comment: What Camel version do you use?

Comment: And the type of outputs is a String[] - eg an array ?

Comment: Yes, it is a String[] and it works.

Comment: Sorry, Maven actually uses camel 2.2.